# Cpanel websocket server : not able to connect from outside client with public domain/URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, sockets, websocket, cpanel

I'm trying to connect my workerman socket server running on Cpanel terminal with the command :

php test_server.php start

[image]

and here is the server code :

```
<?php

use Workerman\Worker;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a Websocket server
$ws_worker = new Worker('websocket://0.0.0.0:2346');

// 4 processes
$ws_worker->count = 4;

// Emitted when new connection come
$ws_worker->onConnect = function ($connection) {
    echo "New connection\n";
};

// Emitted when data received
$ws_worker->onMessage = function ($connection, $data) {
    // Send hello $data
    $connection->send('Hello ' . $data);
};

// Emitted when connection closed
$ws_worker->onClose = function ($connection) {
    echo "Connection closed\n";
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

and here is the client :

```
var host = "ws://example.com:2346"; 
            try{ 
                socket = new WebSocket(host); 
                log('WebSocket status > '+socket.readyState); 
                socket.onopen = function(msg){ 
                    log("\nWelcome status > "+this.readyState); 
                }; 
                socket.onmessage = function(msg){ 
                    // alert('d');
                    log("\nReceived: "+msg.data); 
                }; 
                socket.onclose = function(msg){ 
                    log("\nDisconnected status > "+this.readyState); 
                }; 
            } 
            catch(ex){ 
                console.log(ex); 
            } 
            $("msg").focus();
```

but not able to connect
I have tried to change the server URL to 127.0.0.1, localhost but no luck.

also I have tried the multiple configs for **.htaccess** file as follows :

```
#DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^server/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:2346/$1 [P,L]

#RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:2346/ [P,L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:2346/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %(HTTP:Upgrade) websocket [NC]   # Required to handle the websocket connection
RewriteCond %(HTTP:Connection) upgrade [NC]
#RewriteRule /(.*) ws://exmple.com:2346/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:2346/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:2346/$1 [P,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
  RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Please help and let me know what I'm still missing

**
for the ports: 2346 is publicly open on both side
**

please give me some hints

Comment: What is the output of "netstat -anp | grep 2346" in cPanel?  Are you able to telnet the port from outside (telnet public_ip 2346)?  is that a shared cPanel server?  do you manage the cpanel firewall?

Comment: it shows listening  -> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2346            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      48954/WorkerMan: ma